# Filter DataGridView by a textbox when its datasource is a List (C#)

Tags: c#, list, filter, datagridview

I am trying to create a textbox style filter that would allow me to display only 1 row with selected matching criteria in my dataGridView table.

[image]

The table is currently bound to a list object via datasource.

```
public static List<NpcDrop> npcDrops = new List<NpcDrop>();
//populate npcDrops
dataGridView3.DataSource = Program.npcDrops;
```

This is set this way so I can edit the value in the **dataGridView** and the underlying **npcDrops** list would update itself on cell change. The list is later saved back to the file.

Because of that I cannot convert the list to a DataTable or any other object as this would break the relationship between the dataGridView and the list. I have thought about changing the list to DataTable and then changing it back to the List type but it seems quite impossible to do.

I have tried approaching the problem from various ways:

a) Using BindingSource

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = Program.npcDrops;
bs.Filter = "npcId like '201001'";
dataGridView3.DataSource = bs;
```

However the Filter does not seem to be applied (mostly due to fact that the **BindingSource** based on a List is not **IEnumerable**.

b) by converting my DataSource to DataTable and then using the RowFilter functionality

```
private void searchId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView3.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    string.Format("npcId='{0}'", searchId.Text);
}
```

this however gave me **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** error instead as it seems that it is unable to cast the dataGridView to DataTable.

I have really ran out of the ideas and I am wondering if anyone could help ^^.

Comment: Couldn't you just use ICollectionView and build in filter?

Comment: if I convert the list to ICollectionView doing any changes to the table would not reflect on my list which would break my two way communication between both.

Comment: Have you tried using a [`BindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)?

Comment: There's a sample floating around the internet that is effectively an analog of a System.Data DataView for List<T> data.  It allows for sorting and filtering.  I've used it before in a previous job.  I don't remember where I found it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you may be meaning a “search” instead of a “filter”. If you want to “search” for something as soon as the user types a character, then in most cases, when the user types a single character into the text box, the `searchId_TextChange` event will fire. In this event it appears the code is “filtering” the “Id” from a single character. Unless there is a cell in the table that equals the value the user typed in (which there will not be in this example since it is a single character) …  this will most likely leave the grid in an “empty” state to the user because the filter is not going to return any matches.

Therefore, since it appears you want a single row, then that row will not appear until the user types in the “exact” full number. It may be beneficial to possibly wait until the user has typed in x number of characters before you apply the filter. Or simply add a “search” button next to the text box. I am guessing this may be more user friendly.

Lastly, to help, below are two examples of using a `List<T>` and a `DataTable` as `DataSources` to two `DataGridViews` I will assume the `NpcDrop` property `ID` is an `int`. In this example `ID` is an `int`. In the `DataTable` example, the `ID` is defined as a `string`. Add a couple of text boxes and the form may look something like below.

[image]

The grid on the left has a `List<NcpDrop>` as a data source. The grid on the right used the `DataTable` as a `DataSource`. Initially `fullNPCDropsList` and `gridTable` are filled with the same data. The two text boxes `TextChanged` events are wired-up to “filter” the grid.

When a “filter” is applied for the `List<NcpDrop>`, a new `List<NcpDrop>` `filterList` is created and filled with all the `ID`s that match. This new `List<NcpDrop>` is used as the grids `DataSource`.

When a “filter” is applied to the `DataTable` a new `DataView` `filterData` is created from the initial `DataTalbe` and a `RowFilter` is applied to the `DataView` based on what text is in the text box. This `DataView` is then used as a `DataSource to the grid.

As can be seen from the picture (below) that the left grid will remain “empty” until the user types in the “whole” number. The grid on the right on the other hand will filter the list items when the user types more characters. The grid on the right displays all the items that are like “20102” with five (5) digits. The grid on the left will remain empty until the user types the sixth (6) digit.

[image]

In conclusion, it is not clear what the exact requirements are and what would be the best approach from a user perspective. If a user is searching for a number and the data is a number, I am guessing you will need to do more work as this functionality is not available without using equal, less than, greater than etc…

```
List<NpcDrop> fullNPCDropsList;
DataTable gridTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  fullNPCDropsList = GetData1();
  dgvListData.DataSource = fullNPCDropsList;
  gridTable = GetData2();
  dgvDataTableData.DataSource = gridTable;
}

private List<NpcDrop> GetData1() {
  List<NpcDrop> drop = new List<NpcDrop>();
  int start = 201000;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    drop.Add(new NpcDrop(++start));
  }
  return drop;
}

private DataTable GetData2() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
  int start = 201000;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add((++start).ToString());
  }
  return dt;
}

private void txtListSearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (txtListSearchBox.Text == "") {
    dgvListData.DataSource = fullNPCDropsList;
  }
  else {
    if (int.TryParse(txtListSearchBox.Text, out int value)) {
      List<NpcDrop> filterList = fullNPCDropsList.FindAll(x => x.ID.Equals(value));
      dgvListData.DataSource = filterList;
    }
  }
}

private void txtDTSearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (txtDTSearchBox.Text == "") {
    dgvDataTableData.DataSource = gridTable;
  }
  else {
    DataView filterData = new DataView(gridTable);
    filterData.RowFilter = "ID LIKE '%" + txtDTSearchBox.Text + "%'";
    dgvDataTableData.DataSource = filterData;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! First of all thank you for the answer. I had to use the first method as I have to keep the datasource as List (as it is later saved back to a file). I will see if I will manage to edit the FindAll to allow me to type in partial criteria instead of full number but this is exactly what I was looking for :)